# Access record type name translation from visualforce using $ObjectType

Tags: visualforce, translation

I would like to get the translation of a record type label from a VisualForce page. I cannot find the correct way to access it using $ObjectType, if it's possible.

```
<apex:page language="{!lang}">
    {!$ObjectType.Contact.RecordType['Prospect'].Label
</apex:page>
```

Solutions already tried

- [SELECT ToLabel(RecordType.Name) FROM Contact] in SOQL uses the language of the current user and not the language of the page

Comment: It does not seem to be possible to get translation via visualforce for record type names. But it is possible to query records of RecordTypeLocalization and check if there are any entries for corresponding ParentId (record type id) and Language properties (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recordtypelocalization.htm)

Comment: @kurunve, thanks for your answer. In our use case, we don't want anything in the controller, just visualforce